# Blazor validation errors without any input fields from the user

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, validation, blazor

I am working on a booking app and have a calendar with the dates laid out as buttons so when the user clicks on the desired check in or check out dates it populates my model automatically.

My question is how would I throw my own validation errors when i don't have any `InputText` fields for the user to fill in?

```
// This iterated through the remaining days in the month to properly display the calendar
@for (int i = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(calendarMonth.Year, calendarMonth.Month, i);

    <div class="active">
        <button @onclick="() => SetDate(DateOnly.FromDateTime(date))">@i</button>
    </div>
}

<EditForm Model="@booking" OnValidSubmit="CreateDates" FormName="CommitDates">
    <div class="contact-form-button span-all">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Submit<i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane btn-icon"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="span-all">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int daysInMonth { get; set; }

// status parameter just checks whether we are modifying the check in or check out date value
    [Parameter]
    public bool status { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public DateOnly calendarMonth { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public BookingDatesVM booking { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void SetDate(DateOnly date)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            booking.CheckInDate = date;
        }
        else
        {
            booking.CheckOutDate = date;
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateDates()
    {
        //await _bookingRepository.Create(booking);
    }
}
```

This is my model, the session id is stored using `ProtectedSessionStorage` and retrieved from the parent component and passed into this child component.

```
public class BookingDatesVM
{
    [Required]
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateOnly CheckInDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateOnly CheckOutDate { get; set; }

    public Status BookingStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public enum Status
    {
        InProcess,
        Pending,
        New,
        Approved,
        Declined,
        Cancelled
    }
}
```

I have tried to research this issue and tried some `EditContext` material i saw on here but still didn't give me any output regarding the errors.
I also tried adding the text boxes and populating them with the values but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Sample based on your codes:

```
@for (int i = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(calendarMonth.Year, calendarMonth.Month, i);

    <div class="active">
        <button @onclick="() => SetDate(DateOnly.FromDateTime(date))">@i</button>
    </div>
}


<EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="CreateDates" FormName="CommitDates">
     <div class="span-all">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
    </div>
    
    <div class="contact-form-button span-all">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Submit<i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane btn-icon"></i></button>
    </div>

    
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int daysInMonth { get; set; } = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

    // status parameter just checks whether we are modifying the check in or check out date value
    [Parameter]
    public bool status { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public DateOnly calendarMonth { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public BookingDatesVM booking { get; set; }
    

    private EditContext? editContext;

    private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        booking = new();
        editContext = new(booking);
        editContext.OnValidationRequested += HandleValidationRequested;
        messageStore = new(editContext);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (editContext is not null)
        {
            editContext.OnValidationRequested -= HandleValidationRequested;
        }
    }

    private void SetDate(DateOnly date)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            booking.CheckInDate = date;
        }
        else
        {
            booking.CheckOutDate = date;
        }
    }

    private async Task CreateDates()
    {
        //await _bookingRepository.Create(booking);
    }

    private void HandleValidationRequested(object? sender,
        ValidationRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        messageStore?.Clear();

        // Your validation logic
        if (booking.CheckOutDate.DayNumber > DateTime.Now.Day+5)
        {
            messageStore?.Add(()=>booking.CheckOutDate, "Your  Error");
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ruikai for answering and it was very helpful.
Essentially I used your idea and improvised on it a little.

I changed the EditForm tag to the following:

```
<EditForm OnSubmit="CreateDates" EditContext="editContext">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Book Dates<i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-check btn-icon"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

I had both the Model and EditContext attributes when I tried to utilize the EditContext in the EditForm and also changed the OnValidSubmit to OnSubmit to call the CreateDates method.

Inside the CreateDates method I handled all the required validations using the EditContext. Here is my CreateDatess method:

```
private async Task CreateDates()
{
    valid = editContext.Validate();
    validationMessages?.Clear();

    var checkOutDate = editContext.Field(nameof(booking.CheckOutDate));
    var checkInDate = editContext.Field(nameof(booking.CheckInDate));

    if (booking.CheckInDate == DateOnly.MinValue)
    {
        validationMessages.Add(checkInDate, "Check in date is required.");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (booking.CheckOutDate == DateOnly.MinValue)
    {
        validationMessages.Add(checkOutDate, "Check out date is required.");
        valid = false;
    }

    valid = editContext.Validate();
    //await _bookingRepository.Create(booking);
}
```

Hopefully this helps as an alternative answer.